# What is the Register keyword in C#

Tags: c#, keyword

In C#, I am seeing this code above functions and wondering what it really mean?

```
[Register ("AppDelegate")]
```

Comment: That's not a keyword.

Comment: That's not a keywork, that's an [attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z0w1kczw(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Whatever it is, just wondering if someone can explain what it really mean?

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek - thanks for linking the msdn page.

Comment: What context did you see it in? An attribute isn't necessarily part of the base class library/.net itself. The attribute might be from one of your own projects or some third party lib.

Comment: @CodesInChaos - context is on the following page. http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/hello%2C_world

Comment: Then it's this class: [`MonoTouch.Foundation.RegisterAttribute` Class](http://iosapi.xamarin.com/?link=T:MonoTouch.Foundation.RegisterAttribute) and it's used for interop with objective c classes: [Binding Details](http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/binding_objective-c_libraries/binding_details)

Answer (score 7):

That is not a keyword, that's an attribute, so you might want to read up on that. The attribute would be called `RegisterAttribute`, and I've never seen it before. MSDN doesn't seem to acknowledge its existence either. It can therefore be concluded that it's not a part of .NET, so we can't know its function (unless there's other libraries you're using, in which case you should include them in your post).

Another option it's defined in your very own project (perhaps you imported code from someone else), in which case you should right click on `Register` and select "Go to definition"* to find its definition (thanks @WillemDuncan, that's a better solution).

---

* in MonoDevelop it's "Go to declaration"

Comment: Thanks. Got a msdn page on that, thanks to @MarcinJuraszek - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z0w1kczw(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @itsaboutcode That is not about the `RegisterAttribute` though, that's about attributes in general.

Comment: Rather than searching for the name, right click on the attribute and choose `Go to definition` in the context menu.

Comment: @WillemDuncan Or press F12.

Comment: @ofstream I won't add that, since that's dependent on your settings.

Comment: @antonijn Works for me since I installed it.

Comment: @ofstream But it's still dependent on your settings, and I think this solution is simple enough.

Comment: I didn't add the `F12` shortcut for the same reason. Go-to-definition should also work outside your solution scope, but then you just get information from a file's metadata (comments and definition only, no implementation).

Answer (score 3):

Somewhere in your code search for class `RegisterAttribute`. .Net does not provide any attribute with this name, it must be custom [attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/aa288454%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) defined somewhere in your code (Press `F12` on Register, it will take you to the definition of the attribute) -

```
public class RegisterAttribute : Attribute
{ }
```

Answer (score 3):

It is not a keyword, it is a syntax of *[attributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z0w1kczw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)*.

> Attributes can be placed on most any declaration, though a specific
>   attribute might restrict the types of declarations on which it is
>   valid. In C#, you specify an attribute by placing the name of the
>   attribute, enclosed in square brackets (`[]`),

Since .NET doesn't have a called `Register` attribute, this is probably a custom defined attribute. If you right click on this attribute and after `"Go To Definition"`, you will probably find a custom defined like;

```
public class Register : System.Attribute
{
    private string name;

    public Register(string name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

You can get more information from [`Creating Custom Attributes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sw480ze8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)